# How to off deploy DEBUG logs in Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, logging

I've got hundreds of logs during deploy my Spring Boot app on Tomcat 7. Example:

```
...
13:08:23.361 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'metaDataSourceAdvisor'
13:08:23.375 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter'
13:08:23.375 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mvcConversionService'
13:08:23.375 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mvcPathMatcher'
13:08:23.375 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mvcUrlPathHelper'
13:08:23.376 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'mvcUriComponentsContributor'
13:08:23.376 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'mvcUriComponentsContributor'
13:08:23.376 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration'
...
```

Any idea where from these logs came from and how to off DEBUG type of logs? I've tried to :

- set in log4j properties file `log4j.rootLogger=INFO`, but I think logs didn't came from log4j
- set com.my.app.level=INFO

My `pom.xml`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- deploy on tomcat -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- /deploy on tomcat -->
</dependencies>
```

I'm also getting DEBUG logs in console while application is working

```
14:31:12.034 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to 'http://localhost:8080/myapp/login'
14:31:12.034 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not
 be stored in HttpSession.
14:31:12.035 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
14:31:12.038 [http-apr-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncMan
agerIntegrationFilter'
14:31:12.039 [http-apr-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityCon
textPersistenceFilter'
14:31:12.040 [http-apr-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
14:31:12.040 [http-apr-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.cat
alina.session.StandardSessionFacade@695ad515. A new one will be created.
14:31:12.041 [http-apr-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWrite
rFilter'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your dependencies, i can say you're using `Logback`, not `Log4j`. You can add this to your `application.properties` to turn off spring `DEBUG` logs:

```
logging.level.org.springframework = INFO
```

[About the logging framework:](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging)

> By default, If you use the ‘Starter POMs’, Logback will be used for
>   logging. Appropriate Logback routing is also included to ensure that
>   dependent libraries that use Java Util Logging, Commons Logging, Log4J
>   or SLF4J will all work correctly.

Comment: I added this in my `application.properties` but it didnt help.

Comment: I tried to add this in logging.properties also but result is the same. When I call Logger inside controller `.debug()`, `.info()`, `.warn()` it works (shows only INFO, WARN etc).

Comment: Try `logging.level.root = INFO`

Comment: I've tried set according to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-levels) . It works for logger inside app. When im deploying it i've got DEBUG logs . It's wierd because in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-console-output) they say that INFO is default logging level.

Comment: I'm also getting DEBUG logs in console while application is working. See edited.